# Java Swing TextField looking very small

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to add a textfield next to some check boxes, but for some reason it looks only 1 char in size?

```
JButton addStaff = new JButton("Add Staff");
westPanel.add(addStaff);
// bind the button with the listener
addStaff.addActionListener(new StaffHandler());
c1 = new JCheckBox("Home Only?");
westPanel.add(c1);
c2 = new JCheckBox("Offer ShortHand?");
westPanel.add(c2);
t1 = new JTextField("");
westPanel.add(t1);
```

My output is the following, which looks a bit rubbish.
[image: Screenshot of the resulting Swing]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the constructor `new JTextField(int columns)`

e.g. `JTextField t1 = new JTextField(20);`